# Is there a way for magit to display the branch in the dired buffer mode line for a given directory?

Tags: dired, magit

I'm moving to emacs from shell/Vim and I'm very used to seeing the branch I'm working in when I'm at the project level.  Is there any way to get the Git branch name to display in the dired buffer mode line for my projects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it doesn't. Maybe [dired-k](https://github.com/syohex/emacs-dired-k) can do it, or some other Git related package.

But neither Magit nor VC show this information in Dired buffers. By the way, while Magit uses its own [code](https://github.com/magit/magit/blob/74f792728ef5ffa56fbd51f180bba2ae31620bc7/lisp/magit-mode.el#L694) to update the information displayed in the mode-line of file-visiting buffers, it does so by updating the variable `vc-display-status` the same way VC would. VC's implementation does many other costly things in its respective function, and because Magit updates the mode-line much more often, it needed an optimized implementation.

---

If you want to implement this yourself, then look at the linked function and then adapt it for Dired buffers. Then you would have to loop over all buffers to find Dired buffers (similar to what is being done in `magit-revert-buffers` but much less complicated). Finally to hook this into Magit advice `magit-revert-buffers` to call your function. (I can also add a hook for that, but only once there actually exists code that could use that.)

Comment: That link https://github.com/tarsius/git-elisp doesn't seem to work any more.

Comment: @tarsius is there other way to do it using modern Magit? I tried get this information via `(magit-get-current-branch)` but this throws on buffers like *scratch*.

Comment: Magit still doesn't do this and I don't plan to add it. Before using a function that has to be run inside a repository, make sure you actually are inside a repository (as per `default-directory`).