# Show git branch in dired modeline

Tags: dired, mode-line, git

I would like to see the git branch shown in the dired mode-line at least for the top directory of git projects.

Anyone done this or know how to?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way for magit to display the branch in the dired buffer mode line for a given directory?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/13876/is-there-a-way-for-magit-to-display-the-branch-in-the-dired-buffer-mode-line-for)

Comment: @spav yes I did see that, thanks, though it is about magit, not that I mind - just feels like something dired should handle, and I am surprised noone has done this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I discovered the [git-ps1-mode](https://stable.melpa.org/#/git-ps1-mode) package which does this, yay!

It is in MELPA so it is easy to install and setup.

At the same time I disabled `vc-mode` by setting `vc-handled-backends` to `nil`, to get more mode-line real-estate.

Comment: Please accept your own answer to mark this question answered. (Click on the checkmark.)